# Filter out comment lines from grep output

Tags: command-line, files, grep

What to do if I don't want comment lines in `grep` search result ? i.e. whenever I do search text files, I got result including comment lines.

let's say , I am searching hello :

```
;if(hello) 
hello world
```

In that case I don't want `;if(hello)`  in result.

Comment: Searching using what?

Comment: What type of tool do you want ? `grep` , `awk`, or is it not relevant ?

Comment: 'grep ' command

Answer (score 3):

Use `-v` and regex to filter out output of the first step:

```
bash-4.3$ cat test.txt
;if(hello) 
hello world
;if(hello) 
another hello world

bash-4.3$ grep 'hello' test.txt | grep -v ';.*hello'
hello world
another hello world
```

Comment: OP probably want to omit all lines starting with `;`, and the "hello word" was just an example.

Comment: @fkraiem you're forgetting that comments can be indented too, so line that starts with `;`  won't work in such case, because that line may be starting with tab or space. Sure, I can add additional, but why complicate things if this already works ?

Comment: @fkraiem also op clearly said `let's say , I am searching hello `, so he does search for specific phrase